# Mesh different objects uniformly

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, modifiers

I want the maximum polygon size to be the same for all my objects. I am using the [remesh](https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/remesh.html) modifier to generate many faces, but I would like to specify how dense the mesh is globally, rather than relative to the object's size.

Example:
[image: big mesh]
[image: small mesh]

Here are the settings I'm using for all objects:

```
ob.modifiers["Remesh"].octree_depth = 5
ob.modifiers["Remesh"].scale = 0.99
ob.modifiers[0].mode = 'SHARP'
```

I was thinking I could play with the scale? How would I adjust scale appropriately to get polygons of the same size? Not sure how to go about this..

Answer (score 1):

I do not currently have a Blender here to test my theory, however I am pretty sure, that applying scale would solve your problem. Check the three *scale* values in the *properties* panel. If they are not the same on the two objects, that could be the problem. hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and select *apply scale* so the scale is set to uniform one.

Answer (score 0):

If you join all the objects, go into edit mode and remove doubles --specifying the maximum polygon size for when to remove a "double" -- you may get you're desired result. You could then separate all objects by "loose material" to return objects back to original state.